# Docker changing .conf to directory

Tags: docker, nginx

I'm trying to build a docker image and each time I run

`Docker Compose Up`

It changes my ngnix.conf file to a directory and throws this error;

```
ERROR: for ngnixdocker_web_1  Cannot start service web: OCI runtime create failed: container_linux.go:296: starting container process caused "process_linux.go:398: container init caused \"rootfs_linux.go:58: mounting \\\"/Users/andrew/Desktop/ngnixdocker/.nginx.conf\\\" to rootfs \\\"/var/lib/docker/overlay2/4d2ee251b41131ad9802152f801aee7d79cdf6d0c9debeabcc2e5e40fb7c64cb/merged\\\" at \\\"/var/lib/docker/overlay2/4d2ee251b41131ad9802152f801aee7d79cdf6d0c9debeabcc2e5e40fb7c64cb/merged/etc/nginx/conf.d/default.conf\\\" caused \\\"not a directory\\\"\"": unknown: Are you trying to mount a directory onto a file (or vice-versa)? Check if the specified host path exists and is the expected type

ERROR: for web  Cannot start service web: OCI runtime create failed: container_linux.go:296: starting container process caused "process_linux.go:398: container init caused \"rootfs_linux.go:58: mounting \\\"/Users/andrew/Desktop/ngnixdocker/.nginx.conf\\\" to rootfs \\\"/var/lib/docker/overlay2/4d2ee251b41131ad9802152f801aee7d79cdf6d0c9debeabcc2e5e40fb7c64cb/merged\\\" at \\\"/var/lib/docker/overlay2/4d2ee251b41131ad9802152f801aee7d79cdf6d0c9debeabcc2e5e40fb7c64cb/merged/etc/nginx/conf.d/default.conf\\\" caused \\\"not a directory\\\"\"": unknown: Are you trying to mount a directory onto a file (or vice-versa)? Check if the specified host path exists and is the expected type
```

This is my docker compose.yml

```
web:
  image: nginx:latest
  ports:
    - "8080:80"
  volumes:
    - ./code:/code
    - ./nginx.conf:/etc/nginx/conf.d/default.conf
  links:
    - php
```

Comment: windows or linux?

Comment: I'm running OSX

Comment: Did you solve it?